# Angular 6 built-in date is not working in Edge/IE

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am working with an application in Angular 6. I used the default date and time data type from angular. It load a nice date and time picker in Chrome. However in IE/Edge all I see is a form input.
    Here is the code.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="date" class="form-control reduce-width float-left mr-3" id="changeDetails.changeImplementationStartDate"
      name="changeImplementationStartDate" required #changeImplementationStartDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="changeDetails.changeImplementationStartDate"/>
      <input type="time" class="form-control reduce-width float-left" id="changeDetails.changeImplementationStartTime"
       name="changeImplementationStartTime" required #changeImplementationStartTime="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="changeDetails.changeImplementationStartTime"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge supports [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility) and [time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Browser_compatibility) since v12, IE does not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you means the appearance of the date picker control is different in Edge then it appears in Chrome?

Then yes, similar control appear different in different browsers.

In chrome, it will look like below.

[image]

In Edge, It will look like below.

[image]

This is not an issue. In different browsers it will looks differently.

But it can work correctly, there is no issue with its functionality.

There is no any way available to make its appearance same across all browsers.

It is also not related with Angular 6.

Comment: No, I mean it shows like a textbox. It does not allow you to pick the date/time.